# Google search results too wide in Edge and Chrome at recommended scaling in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, google-search, scaling

I have a 7th gen ThinkPad X1 Carbon with a FHD screen. The recommended scaling is at 150%, which for me works well for almost everything... except this little rendering issue that keeps bugging me.

In Chrome, Edge and Firefox, the results page from Google appears to be too wide when there is an infobox/Knowledge Graph.

[image: Search results for "Switzerland" from Google in Chrome; the page appears to be too wide as shown by the horizontal scrollbar below]

I can solve it by changing the scaling to 125%, but that makes the text too small for me in most apps. Or I could set a custom scaling at ~140%, which seems to be perfect, until I connect to my second screen at home or work, in which case the custom scaling is applied to all displays.

Is there a simple way to make it so that Google result pages are displayed properly at a reasonably large font size, without sacrificing appropriate scaling for other screens?

Comment: I don't know if you noticed, but in your screenshot for Firefox the page has been zoomed out to 90%.

Comment: @iskyfire Thank you, indeed, I did not notice. Then this behaviour appears in all browsers on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?  You can adjust google chrome ui scaling according to this article.

https://www.howtogeek.com/278699/how-do-you-adjust-google-chromes-ui-scaling/

Comment: Thanks, I tried options 2 and 3 but they just make the scaling 100% for Chrome, which is too small for me on 14" screen. Option 1 doesn't appear for me.

Answer (score 1):

## Changing the zoom settings per website

Holding down the control key and pressing the plus and minus keys will zoom in and out on any webpage. The browser will remember the zoom level you selected for each site you visit. For instance, if I zoom out the current page to 80%, every subsequent page I visit on the domain superuser.com will be at 80%.

This could be the solution for you because

A) The browser would remember your selection only for google.com

B) It would readjust the scaling so that the site would fit your screen

## Modifying the default font size in the browser

You might also have some success with changing the default font size.

Here's a page which will tell you how to modify the font size in each browser:

https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000779.htm

Comment: Thank you, this is what I will probably do, even though it is not ideal, as it keeps the scaling when switching screens. Although the reason behind this rendering issue is still puzzling to me.